# Modifier keys settings does not work on login screen

Tags: keybindings, login-screen

I am using a PC keyboard and have to switch the <kbd>Win</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key) and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Opt</kbd> key) for this to feel like a proper Apple keyboard. I have this remapped via System Preferences for my user account just fine.

However, this remapping does not work on the login screen, everything seems to be reverted to as if I haven't done any remapping on the login screen.

As I want to use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+`Letter` to select my face to login without having to touch the mouse it became annoying every time I had to re-remember that the remap only takes effect after I login.

Any suggestion on how can I change the modifier key settings for when I am not yet logged-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist \
    /var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

and restart.

Comment: Should this work also for updating modifier keys?